# Помогите найти проблему

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, почему при изменении размеров экрана(см. скрин) все прислоняется к левому краю и остаётся пробел справа

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1173px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: url('https://w-dog.net/wallpapers/2/4/332444738754522.jpg') no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logotype {
  padding-top: 27px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logotype h3 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  /* Style for "Waxom" */
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 400;
  /* Text style for "Waxom" */
  letter-spacing: -1.36px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 62px;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.menu a {
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.menu a:hover {
  color: #c7b299;
}

.speech {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15vh;
}

.speech h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.speech h2 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.speech p {
  margin-top: 19px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.button {
  background: #998675;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 52px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.works {
  margin: 80px 0;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.single-work {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.single-work:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #f1eee9;
  width: 70px;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 227px;
  right: 125px;
}

.single-work h3 {
  color: #555555;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.single-work p {
  width: 266px;
  height: 62px;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.single-work_icon {
  font-size: 49px;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #fbfaf8;
}

.realization {
  padding-top: 83px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: block;
}

.realization h2 {
  color: #555555;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.realization p {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #261e1b, #493126) no-repeat center top / cover;
}

.purchase {
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.p-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.p-speech {
  height: 150px;
}

.p-speech_main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.p-speech_main h3 {
  color: #c7b299;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.p-speech_main h2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.p-speech p {
  color: #615855;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="heading">
      <div class="logotype">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        <h3>Waxom</h3>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Shortcodes</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="speech">
    <h4>Unique and Modern Design</h4>
    <h2>Portfolio PSD Template</h2>
    <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet</p>
    <p>doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="button" href="https://vk.com/id469310660" target="blank">Get Started</a>
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="works">
      <div class="single-work">
        <div class="single-work_icon">
          <span class="icon-pen"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
        </div>
        <h3>Web & App Design</h3>
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="single-work">
        <div class="single-work_icon">
          <span class="icon-layers"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
        </div>
        <h3>Development</h3>
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="single-work">
        <div class="single-work_icon">
          <span class="icon-gayka"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
        </div>
        <h3>Customization</h3>
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="single-work">
        <div class="single-work_icon">
          <span class="icon-papka"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
        </div>
        <h3>Marketing </h3>
        <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="yellow">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="realization">
      <h2>Waxom is Realization of your Ideas.</h2>
      <p>Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</p>
      <img src="img/3-layers.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="gradient">
  <div class="purchase">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="p-content">
        <div class="p-speech">
          <div class="p-speech_main">
            <h3>Waxom</h3>
            <h2>Multipurpose WordPress Theme</h2>
          </div>
          <p>Don't Forget to Rate the Template. Thanks so much!</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="button" href="https://vk.com/id469310660" target="blank">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: у вас фиксированный wrapper ..может в этом проблема ?сделайте его или в процентах или в vw и потом все margin у вас тоже фиксированные ...надо отдавать это на рассмотрение браузеру

Comment: Делал всё и в процентах, и в vh
Не помогает :с
С марджинами то же самое
На сколько я понял там весь контент присасывается к левому краю, без понятия почему

Comment: если всё сделать на всю ширину то ни что и не куда не будет присасываться ...т.е width100%:;

Comment: У вас есть элемент, который шире контейнера... ))

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1173px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Исправльте стиль на такой и это решит ваши проблемы.
Я избегаю таких проблем оборачиванием всего содержимого body в

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

И следующими стилями:

```
body, div#main {
   width: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```